# Does terraform support azure cosmosdb backup storage redundancy?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm currently on an assignment that requires me to automate azure cosmosdb through terraform. One of the requested features is to have different choices backup storage redundancy like backup intervals, retention intervals, and type of storage redundancy. However, I couldn't find any real documentation aside from some github repo that had some examples, but judging by the comments left, it seems like that was more of a hopeful feature to come. Here is the link to it just incase anyone is wondering: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/12221

I have it setup similarly as shown, but have not yet tried to run it as I need my mentor to walk me through that process - but I do not want to waste time trying to set create something impossible.

I have looked through documentation online to find fragments of things I could use, but in the end, my code ended up looking very similar to what is seen in this repo: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/12221.

Like this to be exact:

```
backup {
    type                = "Periodic"
    interval_in_minutes = "{interval_in_minutes}"
    retention_in_hours  = "{retention_in_hours}" 
    storage_redundancy  = "{storage_redundancy}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/12221) issue you gave, the Terraform Azure provider's for defining backup storage redundancy settings in Azure Cosmos DB is still in development.

There are few other possibilities to achieve this requirement which are given below:

1. It is possible to add `json` code for this using ARM template. After that,  use [`azurerm_template_deployment`:terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/template_deployment#example-usage) and configure the desired back up storage redundancy settings.
2. You can use Azure PowerShell or CLI to update the backup storage redundancy. Refer [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cosmos-db/periodic-backup-update-storage-redundancy.md) document for the relevant information.

[image]

[image]

3. To configure it using terraform, it has to be in the below format as you used.

   ```bash
   backup { 
   type =  "Periodic" 
   interval_in_minutes =  "{interval_in_minutes}"              
   retention_in_hours =  "{retention_in_hours}" 
   storage_redundancy =  "{storage_redundancy}" 
   }
   ```